# How can i use underscored and paranoid in Sql Alchemy, <Flask Python>?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sequelize.js

I want to make a user model for my database. How can I make an [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) user model similar to the following [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) code.

How can I use the `paranoid` and `underscored` Sequelize features. Additionally, how can I include timestamps like `updated_at` and `created_at` in my SQLAlchemy + Flask app?

```
class User extends Model {
}

User.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    is_verified: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    email_verified_at: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    disabled_at: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    remember_token: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    fcm_token: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
    },
},
{
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'users',
    tableName: 'users',
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true
});

export default User;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of declaring a table with SQLAlchemy's ORM, including `updated_at` and `created_at`.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Boolean, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from datetime import datetime as dt

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    email = Column(String(120), index=True, nullable=False)
    email_verified = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    password_hash = Column(String(128))
    created_at = Column(DateTime, index=True, nullable=False, default=dt.utcnow)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, index=True, nullable=False, default=dt.utcnow)
```

Paranoid, also known as soft deleting, does not exist natively in SQLAlchemy. But you can [implement the pattern yourself](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/implementing-the-soft-delete-pattern-with-flask-and-sqlalchemy) if you'd like.

In Python we should use snake case by convention, so we don't need to worry about converting to underscored column names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, 

So, if we want to use soft deletes, we still need to make the soft delete logic manually?

and if i update a database, is the updated_at will be automatically updated to datetime now?

Comment: Yes, the soft delete logic must be manually implement. `updated_at` will not automatically update unless we set `on_update=dt.utcnow` as well in our definition